# Design pattern for Cab service

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to understand design pattern and thought of implementing Abstract factory pattern to see how cab service like ola, uber could be designed.

I started with something of class segregation like below, but got stuck there after.

```
/* Ola has car type as Auto, micro, mini, prime.
 * Later add share car type. 
 * 
 * Add cars to the car type
 * */

enum CarType{
    MINI, MICRO, AUTO, PRIME;
}

public class OlaImplementationAbstract {

    public static void main (String[] ags) {

    }
}

class carFactory{

}
abstract class Car {

    public double fare(double distTravelled) {
        return distTravelled;
    }
}

class Mini extends Car {

    public double fare(double distTravelled) {
        return 9 * distTravelled;

    }
}

class Micro extends Car {

    public double fare(double distTravelled) {
        return 8 * distTravelled;

    }
}

class Auto extends Car {

    public double fare(double distTravelled) {
        return 7 * distTravelled;

    }
}

class Prime extends Car {

    public double fare(double distTravelled) {
        return 10 * distTravelled;

    }
}
```

Could not understand how to proceed further. I just wanted to understand if I got to design such a thing, how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you are a little confused about [**Abstract Factory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) and [**Factory Method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). What you are going to implement is **Factory Method** that returns a `Car` and it can be implemented by following code:

```
class carFactory{
    //use getCar method to get object of type Car   
    public Car getCar(CarType carType){  
        switch(carType){
        case MINI:
            return new Mini();  
        case MICRO:
            return new Micro();  
        case AUTO:
            return new Auto();  
        case PRIME:
            return new Prime();     
        }
         return null;  
    }
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinegdb.com/HyHmtoCMB)

In fact, Abstract Factory is used in some situations that there are different Factory classes with same methods, but in your scenario, there are just some classes with same method.

Comment: Thanks Ali. If I have to implement an abstract factory by changing this scenario a bit. How would  that look like . Could you help me here. Probably this was I will be able to understand the difference better.

Comment: @user1896796 In current code, it makes no sense `Abstract Factory` is implemented, but you can see [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/abstract-factory-pattern/) including this pattern and it is very similar to your code.